# Ability to stack divs using flexbox when window resizes/gets small

Tags: html, css, flexbox, resize

I'm trying to get my divs to stack on top of each other when a page is responsive and resizes, and although I'm using flex wrappers, it doesn't seem to respond when I resize the screen. So on a regular screen, it aligns like this:

picture text

But when I resize the screen smaller, I am trying to make it align like this:

picture

text

Even when using the flex attribute in a wrapper class, it still does not respond to a resizing window, it just gets cut off. Am I utilizing this property correctly? This is what I'm doing:

HTML:

```
 <div class="ext-wrapper">
     <div data-bind="if: !gridVisible()">
         <div class="ext-policy-line-break"></div>
         <div class="ext-loading-width-height">
             <div class="ext-small-screen">
                 <span class="ext-policy-left-load" data-bind="image: imagePath"></span>
             </div>
             <div class="msportalfx-font-bold">TITLE</div>
             <br>
             <div>SUBTITLE</div>
             <div>DESCRIPTION</div>
         </div>
         <hr class='ext-section-line' />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ext-policy-line-break {
   line-height: 20px;
}

.ext-policy-left-load {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ext-policy-loading-text {
   float: right;
}

.ext-section-line {
   color:#A19F90;
   width:100%;
}

.ext-small-screen {
   visibility: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
    .ext-small-screen {
    visibility:visible;
    }
}

.ext-left-margin {
   margin-left: 20px;
}

.ext-add-settings {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ext-loading-width-height {
   width: 562px;
   height:170px;
   align-items: center;
}

.ext-title {
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.ext-wrapper {
   display: flex; 
   width: 100%; 
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
   justify-content:flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a css grid, instead of `float: left` or `float: right`;
This would allow you to change the display when the screen is less then a given amount.
Codepen Example

https://codepen.io/mythius/pen/BazPgNW